# prevent negative numbers but accept decimals in HTML input

Tags: html, angular

I'm looking for a way to prevent a user entering negative numbers , but allow them to type floating numbers

- I'm using angular so angular tools also is a consideration
  Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple `javascript` function on `keypress` and detect when the user enters a `-` and disable that. `event.charCode != 45` detects and disables the user from typing a dash (`-`).

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 45">
```

An alternative to prevent user from enter any type of text and just enable only number you can change the `type` of the input field to `number` and add also the `min` attribute as 0. You can also add `step` attribute to be decimal.

```html
<input type="number" min=0.01 step=0.01 onkeypress="return event.charCode != 45">
```

Comment: `min="0.01" step="0.01"` also, using onkeyup will be better to avoid copy pasting

Comment: Yes true. Forgot about that, just edited the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your solution allows me to type something like --12.123

Comment: Fixed it. I just found out `onkeyup` allows you to type dash. `onkeypress` seems a better approach so I edited it.

Answer (score 3):

I did a directive recently for exactly that purpose. Consider improvements over it.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[money]',
    standalone: true
})
export class MoneyDirective {
    moneyRegex = /^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]+\.$|^[0-9]+(\.[0-9])$|^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])$/;

    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

    @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
    onChange(event: Event): void {
        if(this.ngControl.control?.valid && this.ngControl.control instanceof FormControl) {
            let value: number = +this.ngControl.value;
            this.ngControl.control.setValue(value.toFixed(2));
        }
    }

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(event: InputEvent): void {
        if (!this.moneyRegex.test(this.ngControl.control?.value)) {
            let control = this.ngControl.control as FormControl;
            control.setValue(control?.value?.substring(0, control?.value?.length -1));
        }
    }
}
```

Then just

```
 <input formControlName="price" money>
```